# How to convert NTFS to ext file system without loosing data in zeroin os

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, ext4

I was using windows 11 and switched to Zeroin OS

- I have 2 hard disk on my pc
  1- Agile 240 GB SSD
  2 WD 2 TB HDD (It was having two partition on windows but now showing only one)

After switching from windows to linux i have lost partition maybe due to file format so I think I can recover the files by converting the drive from ntfs to ext4, Please sujjest how can I change the file system without loosing data as cant find any option in KDE partition manager ?
Please check the attached screenshot of the partition:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaKwM.png]

Comment: your image is showing 3 hard disks, not two. you also have an HGST disk. and the disk you have selected in the image is the WDC which does in fact have only one large partition of 1.82TB.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to go from NTFS to EXT without losing your data,
is to back up the data, reformat the partition as EXT, then restore the data.

There is no lossless conversion between the two formats.

Comment: But I can not access the files (as one partition is not showing completely (2 TB HDD had 2 partition in windows system) also i have external hard drive of 1 TB only and I have to backup nearly 1.6 TB

Comment: If the partition has disappeared, you need to recover it. NTFS/EXT are *partition attributes*. Try for example [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: please guide with steps as I am new to linux and do not want to lose my data

Comment: Sorry, never done it on Linux. Read the documentation carefully and go slowly, is all I can say.

Comment: first off, never try to restore data to the disk it was lost from. so step one is getting a second disk of equal or greater size. there are lots of tutorials on testdisk, and they even have a liveCD for it, so you can boot off it. but first, make sure your data is actually missing. I'm not convinced this is a data recovery situation, but just you installing linux and then not knowing how it works. do not try to convert your ntfs disks to EXT or BTRFS or whatever else. copy the data from the NTFS disk to a new drive formatted as the type you want.